# How to hide Text in overlapping View

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i can't find a solution for this problem:

[image]

The Text and charts shines through the background color. How can I make charts and Text fully hidden?
Code example:

```
  <View style={{}}>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', width: 300, height: 200, position: 'absolute' }}>
      <Text>{'Its not overlapping'}</Text>
    </View>
    <Text>{'Text shines through'}</Text>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide both texts behind an absolute positioned `View`, then do not put the `Text` component as a child of this `View`. Furthermore, provide a higher `zIndex` to the absolute positioned `View`.

```js
<View style={{margin:50}}>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', width: 300, height: 200, position: 'absolute', zIndex: 1 }}>
    </View>
    <Text>{'Its not overlapping'}</Text>
    <Text>{'Text shines through'}</Text>
</View>
```

If you want to hide only one text, keep the text as a child and the view will only hide the text outside of the view's scope.

```js
<View style={{margin:50}}>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', width: 300, height: 200, position: 'absolute', zIndex: 1 }}>
        <Text>{'Its not overlapping'}</Text>
    </View>
    <Text>{'Text shines through'}</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Allright zIndex is the magic word. Thanks for the help!